# Comparison between statistical decision theory and supervised learning

Tags: machine-learning, mathematical-statistics, supervised-learning, decision-theory

What are the differences and overlaps between statistical decision theory and machine learning ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The better question to ask would be what is the relationship between statistical decision theory and prediction.  Optimum predictions (e.g., using maximum likelihood estimation or penalized MLE) are needed to make optimum decisions.  Short notes about this are in Section 19.3 of [Biostatistics for Biomedical Research](http://biostat.mc.vanderbilt.edu/ClinStat).  Classfication as used in machine learning plays no role in making optimum Bayes decisions.